# Parsing Substring with Pattern in XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, pattern-matching, xslt-1.0

I need to parse a substring from a value in XPath 1.0 with the following pattern:

```
ValueOfInterestStartOfPattern-1.2.xyz
```

with "**-1.2**" can be optional. I need to obtain:

```
ValueOfInterest
```

Is there a function that can accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by pattern? A regular expression or just a string? It would be better to show an actual example.

Comment: Pattern meaning a fixed string, i.e. Variable in ValueOfInterestVariable-1.2.xyz.

Comment: Then, the answer below works for you. It would have been trivially easy to find out by Googling this, don't you think?

Comment: But does substring-before() fucntion work with regex, i.e. substring-before("ValueOfInterestStartOfPattern-1.2.xyz", "StartOfPattern*\.xyz")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a function that can accomplish this?

Yes: [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before).

---

For example:

```
substring-before('ValueOfInterestStartOfPattern-1.2.xyz', 'StartOfPattern')
```

returns: `"ValueOfInterest"`.

---

### Edit

I have only now noticed that the "xyz" part of your string is **not** optional. You should have written this as:

```
"ValueOfInterestStartOfPatternAnythingEndOfPattern"
```

to make your intention clearer. To make sure that the `EndOfPattern` ("xyz") part is present, use:

```
substring-before(substring-before($string, 'EndOfPattern'), 'StartOfPattern')
```

**Examples**:

```
substring-before(substring-before('ValueOfInterestStartOfPatternEndOfPattern', 'EndOfPattern'), 'StartOfPattern')
```

returns: `"ValueOfInterest"`;

```
substring-before(substring-before('ValueOfInterestStartOfPatternAnythingEndOfPattern', 'EndOfPattern'), 'StartOfPattern')
```

returns: `"ValueOfInterest"`;

```
substring-before(substring-before('ValueOfInterestStartOfPattern', 'EndOfPattern'), 'StartOfPattern')
```

returns an empty string;

```
substring-before(substring-before('ValueOfInterestStartOfPatternAnything', 'EndOfPattern'), 'StartOfPattern')
```

returns an empty string.

Comment: Does substring-before() work with patterns, i.e. substring-before("ValueOfInterestStartOfPattern-1.2.xyz", "StartOfPattern*\.xyz")?

Comment: @Malvon There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0. Going by your question, you don't need it here.